# Using HERE for route optimization and delivery windows

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

New to HERE, so sorry for basic question.
We need to optimize routes. Typically start and end at some location, 20-30 waypoint along the way.  Some of the stops have delivery windows (i.e deliver between 10:00 and 11:00 AM)  some do not. Best way to accomplish this? Any relevant samples we can look at? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is HERE Matrix Routing API, it provides following features:

Large number of origins and destinations (up to 10,000)
Live traffic and historical speed patterns
Car, Truck, Pedestrian and Bicycle modes
Truck attributes such as dimensions, weight, tunnel restrictions and more
Avoiding areas and routing features, e.g., toll roads, ferries and motorways.
Choice between synchronous and asynchronous APIs for flexible result downloads

API document URI https://developer.here.com/documentation/matrix-routing-api/8.3.0/dev_guide/index.html

Request would be like :

POST https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?async=false
Content-Type: application/json
Body:

```
{
"origins": [{"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0}, {"lat": 0.1, "lng": 0.1}, ...],
"destinations": [...],  // if omitted same as origins
"regionDefinition": {
    "type": "circle",
    "center": {"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0},
    "radius": 10000
}
```

}

Another option is HERE Routing API :

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&departure=now&apiKey=<API_KEY>

Answer (score 0):

With the [Tour Planning API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.0/dev_guide/index.html) you can solve many version of the vehicle routing problem. You can set delivery time windows for your depots and you can even specify details about your vehicles.

[Here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started/synchronous-request.html)'s an example with time windows.